# Authenticate user in Java application against Linux operating system user

Tags: java, linux, authentication

Is there a way to authenticate a user in a Java application (spring or like) against the Linux operating system users.
So that I can verify that it is a valid user and that it is member of a specific group?

What I'm think about is that the user is entering his credentials in the application - and before proceeding in the application workflow - the application verify if the user is a valid user on the underlying Linux and based on the groups the user is member of some features are displayed or not.

Comment: You could theoretically hook into PAM, but I've never heard of any setup like this.